# How to scale an Excel app when macro reports are taking over a minute to run?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm running into some scalability issues. Macro reports once took 20 seconds and now they take 3 minutes.

I have an excel sheet("databae") with about 100 columns and 10,000 rows. 90% of cells in each row are formulas.

When running the reports I have to re-calcuate the workbook/worksheet to update the data each loop.  Just a single recalculation takes about 5 seconds so the time adds up quick.

However, I noticed that if I made the database full of static data(no formulas) the report is lightning fast at about 10 seconds.

So this makes me think I need a computer to just update the "database" with all the formulas every few mins and then I can import that static data in my main file and run reports in under 10 seconds.

Is that an ass backwards way to do this or is it a reasonable solution?  What are better options?

It would be nice to keep the "database" in excel because we use some 3rd party addins instead of having to rewrite everything in sql and put in mysql database.

Comment: ... and this is what happens when Excel is (ab)used as a "database". You could look at translating the formulas into VBA and using Variant arrays to calculate in-memory. But really, better to use an actual database IMO.

Comment: The time taken converting it to an actual database is probably worth it in the long run since there is no guarantee that it wont slow down again. Regardless, give it a go?

Comment: @BigBen Arent outputs from cell formulas stored in-memory as well?  How does an actual database do computations different?

Comment: Since it's the formulas that are slowing Excel down, my suggestion was more aimed at doing all calculations with VBA. Though, there's no guarantee that will be faster. Really, Excel is not designed for this sort of setup, and does not scale.

Comment: What kind of formulas are you using?

Comment: @TimWilliams basic multiplication and a bunch of vlookups on tables no bigger than 1000 rows. Along with some a few custom vba financial models